# Get attribute of a generic foreign key

Tags: django, generics, django-contenttypes

I'm still trying to wrap my head around generic foreign keys in Django, so what I've come up with is quite basic so far. I'm trying to create a `NotificationRecipient`, which has a generic foreign key of 2 different models I've already created. These notification recipients can either be a `Client` or an `Account`. I may decide to add more recipients of a new model.

I want to create a `get_email` method in NotificationRecipient, where it checks if the recipient is a contact, client, or account. Then depending on which model it is, it pulls a different attribute.

My existing models look a little like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    primary_email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    ...

class Account(AbstractNamedUser):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    ...
```

Try to get the email depending on the model:

```
class NotificationRecipient(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def get_email_addr(self):
        ''' Gets the model, then pulls the email address. '''
        # Get the model
        # if client:
            # return primary_email
        # elif account:
            # return email
```

How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to define a method on your targeted models rather than building all the business logic in your NotificationRecipient model.

The logic is that the NotificationRecipient model only needs to know that it requires an email address.

```
class Client(...):
    def get_email_addr(self):
        return primary_email

class Account(...):
    def get_email_addr(self):
        return email

class NotificationRecipient(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def get_email_addr(self):

        try:
            email = self.content_object.get_email_addr()

        # if you want to enforce the attribute
        except AttributeError:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('Model requires an email address')

        # if you need a default
        if not email:
            return 'default@email.com'

        return email
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `content_type` field to determine which kind the object is.

But rather than checking the type, you might consider defining an attribute on all the target models which returns the relevant attribute.